# How to deploy a ruby on rails project to a ruby only server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I want to deploy a ruby on rails project on a server without rails. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean, doesn't have rails yet, or is never going to have rails but you want your app dependent on it to work somehow?

Comment: I have rails on my local mac, but I want to deploy it to a server without rails.

Comment: My hoster for my normal website has only ruby and not rails installed and I don´t want to buy webspace on another hoster.

Comment: Strato with the PowerWeb Basic packet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to have ruby installed on your server, but if you cannot add a gem, you can vendor rails into your project so that you won't need to run bundle install or gem install. You can run `bundle package` from the command line to get all of the gems in your Gemfile into `/vendor`.

In the scenario that you cannot execute ruby, or ruby isn't able to be installed, you're out of luck. I'd check out http://www.heroku.com or http://www.engineyard.com for optimized Rails hosting environments, among many others. Some more good info is available on deployments at http://rubyonrails.org/deploy.

Comment: With JRuby, even ruby doesn't have to be on the server.